# Invariant ring for $S_5$

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra, representation-theory, invariant-theory

For the standard representation of $S_5$, the ring of invariants is generated by the elementary symmetric polynomials and hence it is a polynomial ring. Now if we take the tensor product of standard and sign representation, it is again irreducible of degree $4$ but the ring of invariants is not a polynomial ring anymore. Now my question is what are the generators and relations for this ring? Is it known for general $n$ ?